# XML serialization of tab an newline using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

If you look at the the W3C XQuery test K2-Serialization-7.xq:

```
<a>{ codepoints-to-string(1 to 31) }</a>
```

the expected result (according to the W3C test suite) escapes all the characters in the the ASCII range 1-31:

```
<a>&#x1;&#x2;&#x3;&#x4;&#x5;&#x6;&#x7;&#x8;&#x9;&#xA;&#xB;&#xC;&#xD;&#xE;&#xF;&#x10;&#x11;&#x12;&#x13;&#x14;&#x15;&#x16;&#x17;&#x18;&#x19;&#x1A;&#x1B;&#x1C;&#x1D;&#x1E;&#x1F;</a>
```

It's not clear why the tab (0x9) and newline (0xA) characters are escaped at since they're perfectly legal in XML files.  Hence, the expected result seems wrong.  Can anybody explain this?

Comment: After removing illegal XML 1.0 character from the sequence, I can't reproduce this in Saxon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact your expected result is wrong.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

Only in XML 1.1 this was changed. From http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#dt-character

```
Char    ::=    [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

Comment: So, just to clarify: the W3C expected result of escaping tab and newline is wrong for both XML 1.0 and 1.1 -- yes?

Comment: @Paul J. Lucas: Running `<a>{ codepoints-to-string((9,10,13)) }</a>` in Saxon, results in only `#xD` escaped (as it should, because otherwise the XML parser consumer will normalize this character to `#xA`)